# ServiceStack Raw Client query string

Tags: servicestack

This should be simple, but I must be using the wrong key words to find the answer.

How can I output the raw query string that the jsonserviceclient is generating when sending a request to the server?  I know I could use fiddler or something else to snoop the answer to this, but I'm interested if there is something like:

```
  var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://myService:port/");

  var request = new MyOperation
  {
     SomeDate = DateTime.Today
  };

  Console.Out.Writeline(client.AsQueryString(request));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Reverse Routing extension methods](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#reverse-routing) to see what urls different populated Request DTOs would generate, e.g:

```
var relativeUrl = new MyOperation { SomeDate = DateTime.Today }.ToGetUrl();
var absoluteUrl = new MyOperation { SomeDate = DateTime.Today }.ToAbsoluteUri();
```

Comment: Is this only available in ServiceStack 4.0+?

Comment: @Bitfiddler I believe they're also available in v3, if you want to ask questions about v3 please use the `servicestack-bsd` tag.